# How can I change List to List(Array)?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I would like to assign models to List(array(models)) 
instead of 
List(models) ex :

```
final List<String[]> pageRolesOR = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Role1"}, new String[]{"Role2"});

final List<String[]> pageRolesAND = Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Role1", "Role2"});
```

=> with the example below i can get List(Model) but, how can change the models below to List(Array(Models)) please?

```
List<Page_Roles> pr = Page_Roles.find.where().eq("page_id","4").findList();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd probably need a wrapper class around `Page_Roles` that used an array which `findList()` would return that class.

Comment: I don't get it, could you please show me how i can convert list(models) to list(arrays(model.role)) ?

Comment: I don't know what `Page_Roles` is, so I don't know what else to tell you other than, `findList()` cannot return a List of array types.

Comment: It's also unclear what you gain with a `List<Model[]>` instead of a `List<Model>`. I assume you're meaning `List<Model[]>`. You said List(Array(Models)), not `Model` which is not the same thing.

Comment: are you trying to have a list of array objects

Comment: I would like to send to my scala template a List(Arrays(Roles))), not List(Models), then may be i have to loop over models of a list, getting and  assigning roles to a an array then change the array to list(array) 
....all of this is about deadbolt security template restrict.

Comment: In the image below, you'll find more specifics details :
http://imgur.com/a/F2tzr   really thanks

Comment: @FransechkaMargarethe Update your question instead of adding comments. Your comments here contradict your question, refer to missing implementation details, and are just plain confusing as you're not using proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ArrayToList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i+""); //Taking String objects in the list
        }
        Array[] arr = (Array[])list.toArray();  //this becomes array of Strings
        LinkedList listFinal = new LinkedList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(arr); //simply adding same array into the whole LinkedList 
                            //you can add different arrays.
            //So the List(String) --> List(Array(String))
        }

        String[] strArray = new String[10];
        for(int j = 0; j< 10; j++){
            strArray[j] = j+"";   //creating a String array
        }
        LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list2.add(strArray[i]); //Taking String array in the list
        }
        Array[] arr2 = (Array[])list2.toArray();
        LinkedList listFinal2 = new LinkedList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            listFinal2.add(arr2); //simply adding same array of array into the whole LinkedList 
            //So the List(String[]) --> List(Array(String[]))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This help me a lot to get :
Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Rôle Administration", "Rôle Qualité"});
What about a List with many Arrays ? 
Description here : http://imgur.com/a/0p6ay

Comment: Thats great that it helped. I am not sure if I get your question correctly. But if you see the last line.
The last for loop is creating a list of multiple arrays.
Basically, you can add any object to the list. So, an array will act as an
Object to the list. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Excuses moi but the last line do not create multiple arrays, it create one array with multiple values : look at this 
http://imgur.com/a/QukRU
Any way I am really thankful :) Kiss

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, it is not creating multiple arrays, got little confused. I have updated the code for creating a list of Multiple arrays. :)

Comment: Excuse me if I thwarted you, :) you can also use this :
List<String[]> pageRolesOR =  pr.stream().map(Page_Roles::toArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
we can discuss about it later here is my email : j2eealidev@gmail.com

Comment: oh no no dear...that is totally fine. We learn from mistake :)

Comment: @FransechkaMargarethe Did you tried the second scenario. Does it help ?

Comment: @FransechkaMargarethe ok sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used the same method as (Maninder Singh) solution except changing LinkedList by List to convert Models.roles to this kid of List but only for AND not OR..

OR transformation is a little bit difficult...^^ anyways thanks and really thanks

```
// Page Statistics Roles as List
List<Page_Roles> pr = Page_Roles.find.where().eq("page_id","4").findList();


// OR
List<String[]> pageRolesOR =  pr.stream().map(Page_Roles::toArray).collect(Collectors.toList());


// AND
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Page_Roles tt:pr) {list.add(tt.role.getName());}  // Getting List of Strings ( Roles.Names )

String[] array = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);                                  // Convert List to Array

List<String[]> pageRolesAND = new ArrayList<String[]>();
pageRolesAND.add(array);                              //Adding Array to List



/*
 * Examples of Directe Puting Values  
final List<String[]> pageRolesOR = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Rôle Administration"}, new String[]{"Rôle Qualité"});
final List<String[]> pageRolesAND = Collections.singletonList(new String[]{"Rôle Administration", "Rôle Qualité"});
*/
```